# How to make aws appsync api with existing api endpoint URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am new to aws appsync api. Can anyone guide me for this question? 
My Case:

I have one URL of RESTAPI endpoint which returns me JSON. Now I want to convert that RESTAPI to aws appsync api using that URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AWS Lambda resolver to convert the REST API response to GraphQL in AppSync. The [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html) should help you get familiar with Lambda resolvers.

Answer (score 4):

AppSync recently added a Rest API data source as an option and you can use this to map your rest api to a graphql interface.

Comment: Take a look at how you can set this up using HTTP Resolvers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-http-resolvers.html